# How to store a massive number of byte strings while having easy access to any small partion of them

Tags: python, numpy, large-files

Here's my problem. I have a huge dataset of videos. To save space as much as possible, I encode each image frame to a byte string with [PyTurboJPEG](https://github.com/lilohuang/PyTurboJPEG). In this way, each video is a list of byte strings. Then I use pickle to dump this list of byte strings to the disk. When I want to access a certain video, I load the `.pkl` file with `pickle.load` first and then decode the byte strings into `numpy.ndarray`.

This strategy is efficient when I want to access the whole video. However, if I want to access only a part of the whole video, I still have to load the whole video first and then slice it to get a small partition (for example, in some video recognition tasks, the original videos of some dataset are too long and not suitable for training. For each video, we only use a part of it). This method is super io-burdensome and greatly slows the training process.

Is there any solution that we can store a list of byte strings in the disk and only load the part we want to RAM? A possible approach is using [NpyAppendArray](https://pypi.org/project/npy-append-array/), but it doesn't support object arrays (in our cases, byte string) and directly saving the full `numpy.ndarray` instead of byte strings on the disk takes too much space.

A solution that we can store a list of byte strings in the disk and only load the part we want to RAM

Answer (score 0):

I found an elegant solution. Just read the original binary stream. For examples, we have three images in a video, the length of the bytes of the first image is 8192, the second is 8633, and the third is 8321. We save the bytes of all three images in one file named `video.bin`, and the following codes shows how we can access the 2nd and 3rd images without reading the 1st image:

```
lens = [8192, 8633, 8321]    # should be saved when you create the binary file
fp = open("./video.bin", "rb+")
st = 1    # the start index of images we want
ed = 2    # the end index of images we want
ed_offsets = lens.cumsum()
st_offsets = ed_offsets.copy()
st_offsets[0] = 0
st_offsets[1:] = ed_offsets[:-1]    # calculate the start positions and end positions of each image
fp.seek(st_offsets[st])
hyp = fp.read(lens[st: ed].sum())
s = st_offsets[st: ed]
s -= s[0]
e = s.copy()
e[:-1] = s[1:]
e[-1] = len(hyp)
hyp = [hyp[s[i]: e[i]] for i in range(len(s))]
```

`hyp` is the array only containing the 2nd and the 3rd images.
The core functions we use is [`fp.seek`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html?highlight=seek#io.IOBase.seek) and [`fp.read`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html?highlight=seek#io.IOBase.read). See the official documentation for more information.